# Blank at the beginning of each line in idea

Tags: jetbrains-ide, goland

I don't know how it happened, but how to remove blank ?
[image]

Comment: Looks like you are in some Presentation/Distraction Free Mode or alike. Just check `Main Menu | View | Appearance`: exit all modes there. If this somehow stuck from a previous invocation, try entering into such mode and exiting it.

Comment: @LazyOne I am ashamed. It was a Distraction Free Mode. Thank you so much )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are in Distraction Free Mode or alike. Just check `Main Menu | View | Appearance`: exit all modes there.

If you are not in one of those modes and this somehow stuck from a previous invocation, then try entering into such mode and exiting it.